ESP32-S3 board is not blinking on pin 48
I reset the ESP32-S3 board and uploaded simple blink code, but nothing happens
#define LED_BUILTIN 48 

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
 delay(1000);
 digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,LOW);
 delay(1000);
}


ESP32 Arduino platform for some ESP32 boards in pins_arduino.h has a definition of LED_BUILTIN. For example for the "ESP32S3 Dev Module" it is:
#define PIN_NEOPIXEL        48
static const uint8_t LED_BUILTIN = SOC_GPIO_PIN_COUNT+PIN_NEOPIXEL;
#define LED_BUILTIN LED_BUILTIN  // allow testing #ifdef LED_BUILTIN
#define RGB_BUILTIN LED_BUILTIN
#define RGB_BRIGHTNESS 64

The LED_BUILTIN here has a strange value SOC_GPIO_PIN_COUNT+PIN_NEOPIXEL. This is to distinguish normal use of the IO pin from use for the on-board RGB LED. In digitalWrite if the pin is RGB_BUILTIN they invoke neopixelWrite instead of gpio_set_level which is executed for all normal IO pins including 48.
The neopixelWrite function then uses the Neopixel protocol to communicate with the on-board RGB LED.
So don't redefine LED_BUILTIN but use the one already defined in pins_arduino.h.

I checked with Serial Monitor and it printed the value exactly, so what I did, I just removed #define LED_BUILTIN 48 and it worked.
Here is the final working Code.
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);  
  Serial.println("LED Test");// wait for a second
}


ESP32-S3 Board have LED attached at RGBIO 48, thats why I used.

use the following example code as it is neopixle from adafruit.
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h> 

#define PIN 48
#define NUMPIXELS 1

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

#define DELAYVAL 500

void setup () {  
  
  pixels.begin();

}

void loop () {

  pixels.clear();

  for(int i=0; i<NUMPIXELS; i++) {
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0, 150, 0));
    pixels.show();
    delay(DELAYVAL);
  }

}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
